# Cannot find solution to MySQL Lost Update Problem

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency

I'm trying to fix a lost update problem in MySQL, where two sessions do not update with each other. Basically, the question is as follows:

```
A owes B $30. Later, A owes B another $20. In the end A needs to owe both $30 and $20, where A eventually has 50 and B has 150.
```

I have two terminal sessions opened, but not sure how I can solve the concurrency issue. I have searched everything to find solution but having no luck how I can the A and B numbers can have the same result in two sessions.

Below are the step-by-step procedure I am taking from the two terminal sessions.

Session A:

```
UPDATE accounts SET balance = 100;
SELECT * FROM accounts;

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT balance INTO @user1_balance from accounts where id = 1;
SELECT balance INTO @user2_balance from accounts where id = 2;

SELECT @user1_balance, @user2_balance;
```

Session B:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT balance INTO @user1_balance from accounts where id = 1;
SELECT balance INTO @user2_balance from accounts where id = 2;

SELECT @user1_balance, @user2_balance;
```

Session A:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = @user1_balance - 30 
WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = @user2_balance + 30 
WHERE id = 2;

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM accounts;
```

Session B:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts;
```

Session B:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = @user1_balance - 20 
WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = @user2_balance + 20 
WHERE id = 2;

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM accounts;
```

If I run these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the way you've set this up, the lost update is unavoidable. The problem is the selection of the balance into a variable which is then used to update the balance in the table.

This wouldn't happen in a production environment because there's no need to store the balance for later.

If you apply your updates directly as part of a transaction everything should be consistent:

Terminal A:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE accounts set balance = balance -30 where id = 1;
UPDATE accounts set balance = balance +30 where id = 2;
```

Terminal B:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE accounts set balance = balance -20 where id = 1;
-- This update is blocked by the outstanding COMMIT on terminal A. Terminal B waits
```

Terminal A:

```
COMMIT;
```

Terminal B:

```
-- The COMMIT on Terminal A unlocks the rows, so we can complete our update.
UPDATE accounts set balance = balance +20 where id = 2;
COMMIT;
```

Now both terminals show the same result:

```
select * from accounts;
+----+---------+
| id | balance |
+----+---------+
|  1 |   50.00 |
|  2 |  150.00 |
+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to run a `SELECT` to assign user balances. It can be done in `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = balance  - 20 
WHERE id = 1;
```

Note the `balance = balance  - 20`.